# What would be a reasonable price to have a lawyer on retainer?

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, pricing

My players have several times run afoul of the law in their game and have recently been wanting to hire a lawyer. One player was arrested and is awaiting charges for sedition.

**How would a lawyer work in 5th edition D&D?**
I have a week to figure it out! Thanks for any help.

I'm not in an existing setting, but more or less **wanted to know what is a price for a NPC lawyer's services?  I would imagine that a lawyer would be like, a skilled worker, or something similar.**

If this question can't be worded in a way to make it acceptable to the site, I'm not upset if it gets deleted.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn how things work around here. Unfortunately as written this questions isn't a great fit for the site. We aren't a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/48759) and don't work like one, questions need to have a 'correct' answer. Are you playing in an existing campaign setting? If you were playing Waterdeep: Dragonheist for instance we may be able to help within that context but currently this is too broad. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As written, this question seems highly dependent on your setting and its economy. Moreover, the question in the body of the post seems to be soliciting idea-generation, which isn't really a good fit for the RPG.SE format. As a Q&A site, we look for questions to be framed in such a way that you can choose a "best" answer. This sort of question might be better suited to a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/33569).

Comment: @ICTOAN22 I have made an edit that is awaiting peer review that might help keep this from being determined to be soliciting idea generation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*I am not sure if this is exactly how it works RAW but this is how I do it.*

**On p159 of PHB under Services**

I am not gonna quote all of it but this. 
P.159 directly above Spellcasting Services at the end of Services section.

> Skilled hirelings include anyone hired to perform a service that involves a proficiency (including weapon, tool, or skill) a mercenary, artisan, scribe, and so on. **The pay shown is a minimum; some expert hirelings require more pay.**

I charge 2 gp per skill that a lawyer should be proficient in, and 6 gp for expertise.

- Persuasion 6 gp
- Insight 2gp.
- Deception 6 gp
- History 6 gp

20 gp a day or equivalent of Aristocratic lifestyle and profit.

*It isn't specific RAW but I use history for law in my campaigns*

P. 177-178 PHB under Intelligence sub category Intelligence checks

> ***History.*** Your Intelligence (History) check measures your ability to recall lore about historical events, legendary people, ancient kingdoms, **past disputes**, recent wars, and lost civilizations.